# iTerm2 jumps single words not sentence

Tags: iterm2

I know there are lots of pages explaining how to jump between words in iTerms. However, with the latest MacBook 2023 and latest iTerm2 Build 3.4.19, I cannot achieve the desired outcome.

Given `ls -lh /Users/name/Downloads`, by pressing `option` + `left arrow`, I want to jump the word `Downloads`. However, using this [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/293988) or this [page](https://coderwall.com/p/h6yfda/use-and-to-jump-forwards-backwards-words-in-iterm-2-on-os-x), iTerm2 will jump the entire sentence `/Users/name/Downloads`.

Any ideas?